# Conditional Probability of drawing balls

Tags: probability, solution-verification

A bag has $10$ red balls and $12$ blue balls. You draw $6$ times from the bag, without replacement. What is the probability that the first two draws were red given that you drew EXACTLY $2$ red balls?

My attempt:

I am assuming that the problem is equivalent to finding the probability of drawing $4$ blue balls in the last $4$ draws. By this logic, we get

$P($4 blues in 4 draws$) = \frac{12}{20} \cdot \frac{11}{19} \cdot \frac{10}{18} \cdot \frac{9}{17}$

Is this correct or did I make a mistake somewhere? Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Assuming that you drew exactly two red balls:  You want $P( RRBBBB| \{2R,4B\}).$

Comment: @mjw Yes, I meant "exactly". Would my solution be correct then?

Comment: No, please apply the formula for conditional probability.  Also, you need to include the probability of the first two balls being red $\cdots.$

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConditionalProbability.html

Comment: "I am assuming that the problem is equivalent to finding the probability of drawing 4 blue balls in the last 4 draws"  That is your mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Gamma$ be the event $RRBBBB$ and $\Delta$ be the event $\{2R,4B\}$.

$\Gamma \cap \Delta = \Gamma$,

So $$P(\Gamma|\Delta)=\frac{P(\Gamma \cap \Delta)}{P(\Delta)}=\frac{P(\Gamma)}{P(\Delta)}$$

$$P(\Gamma) = \frac{10}{22} \frac{9}{21} \frac{12}{20} \frac{11}{19} \frac{10}{18} \frac{9}{17}$$

$$P(\Delta) =\frac{ \pmatrix{10\\2} \pmatrix{12\\4}}{\pmatrix{22\\6}}$$

Simplifying, this gives $$P(\Gamma|\Delta)= \frac{2!4!}{6!}=\frac{1}{15}$$
which is consistent with Graham's answer which is more elegant.

Comment: I see. It's basic conditional probability.

Answer (score 1):

> My attempt:
>
> I am assuming that the problem is equivalent to finding the probability of drawing $4$ blue balls in the last $4$ draws. By this logic, we get
>
> $P($4 blues in 4 draws$) = \frac{12}{20} \cdot \frac{11}{19} \cdot \frac{10}{18} \cdot \frac{9}{17}$

This is the probability that the third to sixth draws are blue balls given that the first two balls are red. That is *not* what you seek.

---

You are *given* that a specific drawing has exactly two red balls among its six balls.

Each of *those* balls has an equal chance of being in any particular place in this draw.

So you seek the probability that *those* red balls were in the first two among the six positions of *that* drawing.

Ie: that you have obtained 2 from 2 positions when selecting 2 from 6 positions without bias.

Comment: Nice!${}{}{}{}{}$